# How to add class to a javascript link

Tags: javascript

I need to add class="modal_link" to the following href

```
document.getElementById(el).innerHTML = "<a href='//mysitess.com/index.php/disclaimer'><img src=\"//mysitess.com/images/pic.png\"></a>";
```

as it is javascript link I don't know how to add class="modal_link" to the href  link so it openes in modal window.Pls help.

Comment: um..... `"<a class='modal_link' href='//.....`

Comment: what do you mean by add class to href link, are you talking about the a tag?

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript

Comment: um..... "<a class='modal_link' href='//.....  not working

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the answer.

You can set innerHTML and then add the class.

var a = document.getElementById(el).querySelector("a");
a.classList.add("modal_link");

Try this.

Comment: No Sir i just want to add class="modal_link" to this link <a href='//mysitess.com/index.php/disclaimer'> so the link open in lightbox window.

Comment: OP will not say what the library is so impossible to help.... Has nothing to do with the class, but what uses the class.